# How to change ProductCode and ProductName when building

Tags: windows-installer, nant, vdproj

I have a Windows Installer project that installs a service. I use NAnt build to build my .msi install for two configurations at a time: SiteProd and SiteTest. These .msi's install a Windows Service.

To allow side-by-side installs, I need to be able to change the ProductCode and ProductName of the SiteTest install when building. I can do this either by changing the .vdproj file before building or within the .msi after the project has been built. Either way, how can I use NAnt to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to find going down that path with that tool very difficult.  For example your service is no doubt installed using a ServiceInstall custom action which has the service name hard coded into it.  You won't be able to transform that in your build process.

Far more trivial using another tool but you'll have to ask me to name it if you want to know more.  Otherwise I'm sure I'll be downvoted.